# Hide URL preview of Twitter tweet

Tags: twitter, automation

I have a Twitter button on my website to allow people to tweet from the site. I am setting the text of the tweet programmatically and I’m also including a link to my site.

Everything works except that Twitter is turning the link into a preview of my website. I don’t want the preview. I want the link to stay a link.

Is there a way to do that?

From this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erjLE.png)

I get this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qNF4.png)

But I want this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96CXg.png)

Comment: Does encoding the link work? e.g., replacing `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`. Or try the JavaScript `encodeUri` function.

Comment: Encoding does not seem to work. I use this URL:  http%3a%2f%http://2fwww.quotecandy.com   . Twitter did not recognize this as a URL.